# Namespace SfCalendar not found but when I try to add it, it says that using directive is not necessary?

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 to make a cross-platform iOS/Android app. I'm trying to add a calendar using SfCalendar, but it says that the name cannot be found. When I add:
        `using Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms;`
it tells me that the directive is not necessary. This is how I'm declaring the calendar:
        `SfCalendar cal = new SfCalendar();`
Do I need to do something differently?

Comment: You could read this document : https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/introduction/download-and-installation

Comment: I have already read the documentation and I'm using the same syntax that they have, but I'm still getting an error that the namespace cannot be found. I think Micah's answer is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the control correctly per [Syncfusion's documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfcalendar/getting-started#create-a-simple-sfcalendar).

Make sure you are including the correct assemblies (DLLs) in the correct projects. See [this](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/introduction/control-dependencies#sfcalendar) link for instructions on how to do that.

To add an assembly to a project, right click on the project in Visual Studio and then click `Add`, then `Reference`. Select `Browse` on the left and then `Browse` on the bottom and then browse for the DLLs you need.

[image: VS Solution Explorer]

[image: Assembly Browser]

Comment: That link doesn't really have instructions, just a list of dll names. How can I make sure that the correct assemblies are included?

Comment: @pineapplejordan please see my edited answer for information on how to add assembly references.